# PHP классы и объекты

Tags: php

Имею 3 класса для примера:
Этот класс бы я хотел получать во всех других без объявления в других классов, без вылавливливания его в конструкторе.

```
class Информация { 
    function конфигурация() {
        return array('password' => '123456');
    }
}

class SomeFunction {
    function echo_conf() {
         var_dump($информация->конфигурация());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Информация { 
    public static function конфигурация() {
        return array('password' => '123456');
    }
}

class SomeFunction {
    public function echo_conf() {
         var_dump(информация::конфигурация());
    }
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: А есть еще подобные методы?

Comment: в каком плане подобные методы?